# Is there any way to get ubuntu 13.10 to stop asking for my password

Tags: password, default

I've always found this feature quite annoying and when I try to turn it off or simply just clear the password it still prompts me for a password. Everytime I've done that I've had to reinstall ubuntu all over again because nothing I put in will work. It keeps asking for authentication on EVERYTHING!! I can't even do a simple search of MY OWN FILES AND PROGRAMS without being prompted for a password.

I did a format and reinstall recently and I didn't have this problem until something popped up asking for my password for a keyring. I saw this A LOT before I reinstalled but it wouldn't let me install some software I needed until I did. Ever since, this stupid keyring thing is ALWAYS asking for a password.

Answer (score 0):

If you use auto-login and your keyring password is different than your login password you can remove the keyring password in „Passwords and Encryption Keys“:

[image: Passwords and Encryption Keys]

There should be entries listing different passwords. Right click there and change the password. If not, check the settings:

[image: screenshot]

For using sudo without being prompted for a password, you might use an USB Flash Drive [USB Flash Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376957/identification-and-authentication-methods-in-ubuntu) for authentication:

```
 apt-get install libpam-usb pamusb-tools
 pamusb-conf --add-device YourUSB
 pamusb-conf --add-user Username
```

Comment: I just tried that. There were only two records there and neither had the password I use for keyring. In fact, one had a password I don't even recognize and have never used (as far as I know). Its really long and looks like this %00%00%00%01%00%00%00%0C

Comment: Could you enable "by keyring" and "Show any"?